# Having a compiling error with Python using PyCharm 4.0.5

Tags: python, pycharm

The reason for me asking the question here is that I did not find a solution elsewhere. I'm having the following error with my PyCharm 4.0.5 program while trying to run a Python script. It was working fine the one day and when I tried using it this afternoon I got the following error after tying to run a program which I am 100% has no errors in it.
In the message box I got the following error:

```
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site.py", line 562, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site.py", line 544, in main
    known_paths = removeduppaths()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site.py", line 125, in removeduppaths
    dir, dircase = makepath(dir)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site.py", line 90, in makepath
    dir = os.path.join(*paths)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have never seen an error of this kind and don't know where to start tackling this problem.

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

The code looks like the following, and I seem to have forgotten to mention that it gives me the exact same error for every single .py script on my computer.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
alex = turtle.Turtle()


def hexagon(var):
    for i in range(6):
        alex.right(60)
        alex.forward(var)


def square(var):
    for i in range(4):
        alex.forward(var)
        alex.left(90)


def triangle(var):
    for i in range(3):
        alex.forward(var)
        alex.left(120)


def reset():
    alex.clear()
    alex.reset()
x = True
while x:
    alex.hideturtle()
    choice = input("""
    Enter the shape of choice:
    a. Triangle
    b. Square
    c. Hexagon
                    """)
    if choice.lower() == "a":
        length = input("Enter the desired length of the sides:  ")
        triangle(int(length))
        restart = input("Do you wish to try again? Y/N  ")
        if restart.lower() == "n":
            x = False
        else:
            reset()
    if choice.lower() == "b":
        length = input("Enter the desired length of the sides:  ")
        square(int(length))
        restart = input("Do you wish to try again? Y/N  ")
        if restart.lower() == "n":
            x = False
        else:
            reset()
    if choice.lower() == "c":
        length = input("Enter the desired length of the sides:  ")
        hexagon(int(length))
        restart = input("Do you wish to try again? Y/N  ")
        if restart.lower() == "n":
            x = False
        else:
            reset()
print("Thank you for using your local turtle services!")
```

Comment: It would be great if you could attach your .py script.

Anyway do use any kind of virtual env for python?

Comment: Show your code please. You need to ensure you put together a proper [mcve] in order to give the readers the necessary information to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: I shall edit and post the code now.

Comment: I added the entire code as it's not that long and I don't know if it's the code or PyCharm causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have a python file named `os.py` which is being imported instead of the "real" os module.

Comment: Will check that out.

Comment: Any way to find out if the os.py was replaced by a fake one somehow as I just verified that the code is unchanged and that it is the "OS" module giving the error.

Comment: `print(os.__file__)` will print the full pathname to the os module file.

Comment: And I would recommend putting that `print` statement inside one of the scripts instead of just running it by itself, to be sure that you're replicating the exact environment.

Comment: Wow.... I'll just delete that comment... Anyway I found out that the `os.py` does not seem to have any errors and that it seems to be the `site.py` giving me the error. The reason for me not running it in a script is because  it can't run any script of any kind at the moment.

Comment: No matter where the error is happening, inside `site.py` or somewhere else, the error message is clear: the `os` module does not contain anything named `path`, and by far the most likely explanation is that you have your own local module named `os.py` which is being imported instead of the real system module.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, I found another `os.py` file in the `lib` folder of my Python. Why it was there I have no idea and I would never have thought to look for it there. Thanks again. @John Gordon